# sentence check: "my headphones cable got caught on (to) a book?"

Tags: phrase-choice

sentence check: "my headphones cable got caught on (to) a book?"
Is it right to say ‘my headphones cable got caught on (to) a book?’ im not quite sure i just came up with this... does it sound right?

Below is what i just saw:

But the have this assymetrical headphone cord, and I just cannot figure out how I am supposed to wear these things comfortably. I've tried it with the cord in front of my neck, behind it, over my ears, under my shirt, but it just doesn't seem to work. Either there is too much weight on one ear, or there's too much cord and it keeps getting tangled, or it just ***gets caught on something***. Plus, it looks stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Catch on** is a perfectly idiomatic compound verb. **Catch to** is not.

EDIT: **Catch onto** is also idiomatic.

Comment: The OP may mean "catch onto"; not "catch to". :)

Comment: @ Catija Ahh, good point. Thank you. I shall edit.

Comment: I see! so i can either say" my headphones cable got caught on a book " or "my headphones cable got caught onto a book"? to express the headphones cable is entangled with a book  @Jeff Morrow

Comment: @ Cry Personally, I'd stick with **on**. You will certainly hear **onto**, but, at least in my part of the US, it is primarily colloquial and informal.